# values to be taken from script mongo

Tags: mongodb, shell, perl, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper

please assist how can we achieve this:

```
/home/bin/mongoexport --host pr01.prod.com:3046 --authenticationDatabase admin -u m7@pub.com -p 'orc1*&'
 --readPreference secPref --db action --collection pubaction --type=csv -f "_id" --sort "{_id:-1}"
 --noHeaderLine --limit 1 -o /opt/app/maxvalue_id_rt24.csv
 
2021-04-01T00:48:22.721-0400    exported 1 record
$ cat /opt/app/maxvalue_id_rt24.csv
ObjectId(60659ac)


  $ cat lastvalue_id_rt24.csv
ObjectId(60654fe)
```

--- **we are putting   manually lastvalue in  lastvalue_id_rt24.csv  file  for the first time run the automated script**

```
OUR QUERY ---- db.getCollection('pubaction').find({"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId("60654fe") ,"$lte":ObjectId("60659ac")}})
```

**My requirement here to cut  the value inside () in maxvalue and lastvalue to the next script  and pass value x=60654fe And y =60659ac**

```
$/home/bin/mongoexport --host pr01.prod.com:3046 
--authenticationDatabase admin -u m7@pub.com -p 'orc1*&'
 --readPreference secPref --db action 
--collection pubaction --type=csv -f "_id,eventId,eventName,timeStamp,recordPublishIndicator" 
 -q '{"_id":{"$gt":'$minvalue' ,"$lte":'$maxvalue'}}'  -o /opt/app/act_id_rt24.csv

So inside script -q '{"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId("x"),"$lte":ObjectId("y")}}'  --- we  will need to hardcode ObjectId And pass the x and y values

ex: from above output

 -q '{"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId("60654fe") ,"$lte":ObjectId("60659ac")}}'
```

**in next run in below script we must change the logic, to put the old ID value in MINVALUE and NEW ID VALUE IN MAXVALUE**

```
/home/bin/mongoexport --host pr01.prod.com:3046 
--authenticationDatabase admin -u m7@pub.com -p 'orc1*&'
 --readPreference secPref --db action 
 --collection pubaction --type=csv -f "_id" --sort "{_id:-1}"
 --noHeaderLine --limit 1 -o /opt/app/maxvalue_id_rt24.csv
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
maxvalue=`cat maxvalue_id_rt24.csv`
echo $maxvalue
minvalue=`cat lastvalue_id_rt24.csv`
```

and after sqlldr:

```
sqlldr report/fru1p  control=act_id.ctl ERRORS=500 log=x`.log direct=Y

we  MUST change  LOGIC below   to put the old ID value in MINVALUE and NEW ID VALUE IN MAXVALUE

cat maxvalue_id_rt24.csv > lastvalue_id_rt24.csv
```

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: HI Experts, any suggestion on this.